# Android: (In work profile in Android Device)packageManager.queryIntentActivities returning empty list in targetSDKVersion 33

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-manifest, android-gallery

I have created a app which need to be worked in **work profile** in android phone. I need to upload image from Gallery(there is no gallery app or photos app available for **work profile**). For personal profile same app works fine but for **work profile** it doesn't.

**targetSDKVersion 33**
I have applied following code in Manifest file.

```
<queries>
    <!-- Camera -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
    <!-- Gallery -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Also have provided this permission.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

But unfortunately following code return an empty list in **work profile** app but not an empty list in personal profile app.

```
packageManager?.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
```

Please help me in making this work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "there is no gallery app or photos app available for work profile" -- what activities are you expecting to be returned by `queryIntentActivities()`? What is the value of `intent`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Actually I need to crop the image after selecting it from Gallery/photos. So I am able to select the image from Personal profile gallery, but for cropping the image I'm doing queryIntentActivities which return an empty list.

Comment: What is the value of `intent`?

Comment: Intent { act=com.android.camera.action.CROP dat=content://appPackageName.debug.provider/external_files/Android/data/appPackageName.debug/files/crop/TEMP_FILE_URI_STORED_ADDRESS.jpg typ=image/* }

Answer (score 0):

First, [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). You are relying on an undocumented and unsupported `Intent` action that only exists on some devices.

Second, if you are supplying content to another app, it is your job to supply a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard (`image/*`).

Third, none of your `<queries>` declarations matches your `Intent`. If you are getting any results back, it is by happy accident.

Fourth, even if your device does support a `CROP` `Intent`, it might not be available in the work profile.

There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45?sort=created). Please use one. That will avoid all of these problems.

Comment: Thanks will try by using image cropping library.

Comment: I tried using https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop cropping library but corresponding to destination URI I'm everytime getting FileNotFoundException.
I tried several ways of creating temp file and using it as destinationUri but get FileNotFoundException only. 
Can u plz help?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /fileName: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: @AyushAgrawal: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] for how you are using the library and provide the complete stack trace associated with your exception.